# how to maintain session.sessionId in asp.net without displaying sessionId in url

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I am working on a asp.net web project in which if I use

in web config

then the encrypted sessionId is visible in URL but if I change cookieless to false then encrypted sessionID get removed from url but I receive a new session.sessionId on each request

Please help so that no encrypted session.sessionID is visible in url and also there should be SINGLE session.sessionId on every request.

Comment: make sure your browser is allowing session cookies to be saved

Comment: Is your browser set to disallow cookies?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using cookies based session management ASP.NET is using some optimalization which results in creating new session every time until there are some actual session data to store. To avoid this you can put a dummy value into session in `Session_Start` event available through `Global.asax`:

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["DUMMY_KEY"] = "DUMMY_VALUE";
}
```

This way the session id will remain the same until the session time out occurs.

Comment: I am using session.sessionId which is giving me a new Id everytime a new request is made.  
and If I use cookieless to true then I get same SessionId but It shows encrypted data in website url

Comment: @user1574078 Yes and this will be happening until you put some value to be stored into session. This is by design so empty session doesn't have to be serialized/deserialized and stored. In other words ASP.NET is assuming that if you haven't put anything into session you doesn't need it. In case of putting session id into URL ASP.NET doesn't do that because it would complicate distinguishing between session expired and no session.